# how to show a menu based on taxonomy in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make a drupal site. I have named the vocabulary as category. Now I want to show a specific menu in the sidebar based on the category term.
For example , if I am on a node which has "mobile" in the category term, so it should show only  "mobile" sub-menu terms  in the menu block.
I have search around but could not find any solution. Any way to work this out? it seems views also don't have this feature.

Comment: I am still unable to figure out how it would with views. any help :/

Comment: Just to clarify: is your problem getting the specific menu to show on the correct pages, or is the problem that you're trying to show only certain items of the menu depending on the page?

Comment: @Boriana I am trying to show only certain items of the menu depending on the page

Comment: Ah ok... I think the answer below should work.  I just got confused by the question title.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple,use the taxonomy menu module [link to the taxonomy menu module](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution for anyone who comes here:

I wanted to have one content type that would display a different menu depending on the taxonomy term I set for each piece of content. To do this I created a pathauto pattern for my content type which would set the url alias based on the taxonomy term.  Then, I created a different menu for each taxonomy term. Then, I placed the block in the block layout, and in the block configuration settings restricted each menu based on the path.

Now, whenever I create a piece of content, all I need to do is go into the 'menu settings' sidebar and add the content to the desired menu.  Then, placement via weights can be done easily through the menu ui.